# Are isomorphic plane curves projectively equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ and $D$ be two projective plane curves (over $\mathbb{C}$) of degree $d>1$. Suppose that $C$ and $D$ are isomorphic.

**Are $C$ and $D$ projectively equivalent?**

For smooth curves this is a theorem by M. Noether. So we may restrict to the singular curves.

Any reference, idea or counterexample will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hartshorne's generalization of Noether's Theorem - [Theorem 2.1 here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250520873) - we have that a generalized divisor $L$ on  a plane curve $C$ of **degree at least $4$** satisfy $h^0(C,L)=3$ **if and only if** $L$ is given by a hyperplane section.

Then we follow the same argument of [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/164134/82672) to conclude that an isomorphism $\phi: C \to D$ has to be the restriction of an element of $\mbox{PGL}(3,\mathbb{C})$.

It remains to prove in low degrees. This can be done by describing all possible **singular** curves. However the assertion is false for degree three smooth curves.